# ¿Cómo instalar la librería netCDF4 de python en ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, librería

Mi problema es el siguiente: quiero instalar la librería `netCDF4` en python para poder trabajar con archivos .nc

Voy a la terminal de ubuntu y pongo: `pip install netCDF4`

Y me aparece el siguente error:

> Collecting netCDF4   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/27/f90bd3ff2190f3fa4ecc755acadd0842e2350b424dbd68bbc693af1dcf48/netCDF4-1.4.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
>
> Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7 in
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from netCDF4) (1.11.0) Collecting
>   cftime (from netCDF4) Installing collected packages: cftime, netCDF4
>
> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13]
>   Permiso denegado:
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cftime-1.0.2.1.dist-info'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Por lo que entiendo no me deja instalar la librería y la administradora de la computadora soy yo. 
¿Alguien sabe cómo se resuelve?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece un problema de permisos, lo que necesitas son superpoderes (sudo):

```
sudo pip install netCDF4
```

o en su defecto el envoltorio que incluye las librerias adicionales:

```
sudo pip install netcdf
```

Comment: gracias! Me ayudó mucho tu respuesta